# How to write if-else in assembly?

Tags: if-statement, assembly

How do you write the if else statement below in assembly languange?

C Code:

```
If ( input < WaterLevel)
{
     MC = 1;
}
else if ( input == WaterLevel)
{
     MC = 0;
}
```

Pseudocode

```
If input < Water Level
Send  1 to microcontroller
Turn Motor On


Else if input == Water Level
Send 0 to microcontroller
Turn Motor Off
```

Incomplete Assembly: (MC- Microcontroller)

```
CMP Input, WaterLevel
MOV word[MC], 1

MOV word[MC], 2
```

Comment: With conditional branches...

Comment: Yes rest assured i just started learning this today.. I am a student..

Comment: @Ped7g Coming from an old man with 30 years of coding experience, i think you should have more respect for youngster trying to learn. I am here on stack to learn, eventhough i dont even a grasp of the basics yet. If i had 30 years of experience like you old man i wouldnt be on here would I? Be more respectful. And if it doesnt answer the question, go away. Nobody needs you around.

Comment: I give zero respect to bad code. Even if it's my own. If you are student, I have respect to you as a person and to your effort to learn. Not to that particular `else` branch, which is fundamentally wrong. As a student you should rather try to figure out why, or ask for reason, than asking for respect - that will do little good to you, even if I would comply. If you are asking me to have empathy with your view, try also mine. I'm much more worried about such code slipping into real product, than I'm worried about being nice. Being rude does hurt people less than a water flood.

Comment: @Ped7g Its my first day of learning assembly language and your worried that such a code will slip into a real product. At least I have now understand the statements with the answers provided to me by other users. All Im saying is, what are you doing here if you arent here to answer my question? What help could i possibly get from your 'concern' of bad codes.

Comment: I said *fundamental* problem, it's not related to assembly. What help could you get: actually quite some, if you will leverage this information to improve your way of dealing with [programming] problems. Problem is: your example does switch motor off only when certain accurate water level is reached, and by "input" it looks like reading of sensor. With integers this would mostly work, with `float` almost never, but it's dangerous design even with ints. Actually this important "detail" prevented me from posting answer dealing with "if/else in asm" itself, my brain couldn't get over it, sorry.

Comment: BTW, I had little chance to figure out you are student, and SO is full of people solving real world problems and unfortunately sometimes asking similar questions like yours (I mean similar in the way how they are trying to achieve something unintentionally malicious, in good faith they are doing something great). I'm very likely pushing this way too much. Deal with it. I just hope you will manage to extract also some knowledge from this, otherwise I just wasted time of both of us.

Answer (score 21):

If we want to do something in C like:

```
if (ax < bx)
{
    X = -1;
}
else
{
    X = 1;
}
```

it would look in Assembly like this:

```
 cmp    ax, bx      
 jl     Less  
 mov    word [X], 1    
 jmp    Both            
Less: 
 mov    word [X], -1  
Both:
```

Comment: How to write the equal condition (in the question) in assembly? Your example has an else statement while mine uses an else if.

Comment: je    equal means jump to equal, if equal

Comment: There's not only one assembly language. Assembly for ARM obviously must be different from Sparc, MIPS or x86. They all have different instructions for comparison. You must specify the architecture. About `else if`, the latter `if` is just another block of code in else.

Comment: It's x86 Assembly Architecture

Comment: CMP  Input, WaterLevel
JE       Equal 
MOV  word[MC], 1
JMP    Both
Equal:
MOV  word[MC], 0
Both:



How would i have tested for the (input<water level) condition if i used this.

Answer (score 9):

Not knowing the particular assembly language you are using, I'll write this out in pseudocode:

```
compare input to waterlevel
if less, jump to A
if equal, jump to B
jump to C
A:
send 1 to microcontroller
turn motor on
jump to C
B:
send 0 to microcontroller
turn motor off
C:
...
```

For the first three commands: most assembly languages have conditional branch commands to test the value of the zero or sign bit and jump or not according to whether the bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

To use if statement in NASM assembly first line should write:

```
comp eax, ebx
```

In this line NASM understands that it should compare two registers.
Now u should specify how NASM assembly should compare them.
Lets compare for example if greater or equal:

```
main:
    comp eax, ebx
    jge greater_or_equal
greater_or_equal:
    ; your code if greater or equal
```

Please check the **link** for other jumps.

https://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/academics/qhamarsheh/uploads/Lecture%2018%20Conditional%20Jumps%20Instructions.pdf