# How to write If only statement in assembly?

Tags: assembly

How do i write the following code in assembly?

```
if(Input<WaterLevel)
{
     MC = 1;
}
```

I know how to do an if else statement but what about an if statement without the else.

Comment: it will react the same like if its true it will go inside otherwise it will ignore it

Comment: You just leave the else part off, just like in any other language? Also please don't tag languages that aren't relevant. Also there are many different assembly languages, there is not just one answer.

Comment: you test the condition, and jump over that block if the test fails

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? It will work exactly the way you wrote in the question, you don´t need an `else`.

Comment: `move Input, d0` `cmp d0, WaterLevel` `blt $1` `moveq #1, MC` `$1:`

Comment: Really tempted to close this as a duplicate of [your question about if-else from 5 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602029/how-to-write-if-else-in-assembly).  How is it not obvious that this is just a subset of the problem you already got answers to?  Did you not understand those answers?

Comment: *"I know how to do an if else statement"* - doesn't look like that. Besides that, your way of thinking looks a bit too flat and low, you actually never *need* `if` and `if-else` in your code. Those themselves do nothing. What you probably need is to execute different action when `(Input<WaterLevel)` and different one when `(Input>=WaterLevel)` and using `if`-like construct around that is just one way to achieve it. In some cases (depends on the wanted actions) you may solve that without `if` in completely different way. Ie. would somebody forbid you `cmp`, it's still possible to code anything.

Answer (score 1):

You use a conditional jump which executes only if the condition is false.
Example (pseudocode):

```
        ...
        CMP $Input, $WaterLevel   ; compare variables
        JGE Continue              ; if $Input >= $WaterLevel, jump to "Continue"
        MOV $MC, 1                ; set $MC value
     Continue:
        ...
```

EDIT: As Thilo pointed out, you need to use the opposite of your condition for the conditional jump.

Comment: Note that you had to reverse the condition: Not "if true, execute block", but "if false, jump away".

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put anything after the cmp would do it.

From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_conditions.htm

```
CMP DX, 00  ; Compare the DX value with zero
JE  L7      ; If yes, then jump to label L7
.           ; Continue as normal. No else.
.
L7: ...
```