# if-elif change value being checked once condition is met?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to wrap my brain around this and am pretty confident that the following will cause a problem. Looking for confirmation

```
if row['High'] < sl_c:    # Check if SL is being hit
    sl_ci = row['Low'] + sl
    # sl_ci = row['High'] - sl  # chenge sl which is being looked for.
    if sl_ci < sl_c:  # Verify sl_ci is greater than current
          sl_c = sl_ci
          buy_l[key].at[e, 'sl'] = sl_c  # Input sl to dfent
          buy_l[key].at[e, 'sltime'] = row['Time']  # Input time of sl modification
          # buy_l[key].at[e,'sl'] = sl_c
elif row['High'] > sl_c:  # If SL is hit
     buy_l[key].at[e,'Buy'] = sl_c  # input the sl_c as exit
     buy_l[key].at[e, 'CloseTime'] = row['Time'] # input the time of exit
```

As you can see `sl_c` is being checked in the first `if` statement and the nested `if` is checking it against the second condition `sl_ci`. When both conditions are met we change a certain value.

The `elif` is checking for `sl_c` which I believe is being modified above and might meet/reject the condition based on the new value?

This might be clearer

```
if x == -1:
     y= -2
   if y < x:
      x=y
elif x<-1:      # Will the value be checked even though above if condition is met? 
                # if it will be, then will the x value being checked be -2?
```

Comment: Like in all languages if-else is mutually exclusive, you'll never execute code from both blocks. If the the test passes the `if` block will be executed otherwise the `else` block will be executed. You can have a look at what assembly code looks like for if-else statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40602071/1720199

Comment: Why don't you just try your reduced example?

Answer (score 0):

the `elif`'s condition is never evaluated, because the first `if` is hit. `elif` is just like a nested `else: ... if:`

we can change your original example a little to make sure the condition is never even evaluated by changing it to a function with side effects:

```py
def bool_func_with_side_effect(x):
    print("INSIDE FUNC! x:", x)
    return x<-1

x = -1
if x == -1:
    print("inside if #1")
    y=-2
    if y < x:
        print("inside if #2")
        x=y
elif bool_func_with_side_effect(x):
    print("inside elif")
```

Output (unsurprisingly):

```
inside if #1
inside if #2
```

Comment: note: you can even call a non-existing function, and it will not throw an error because it is never evaluated

Answer (score 0):

No, the value will not be checked in `elif` part once it matches the condition in `if` part.

This is the control flow. If the condition didn't match in the first `if`, then it will check for condition in `elif`. Once any of these condition is true and programs enters into that block, rest of the conditions will not be checked.

However, if you want to get the condition `elif` checked too, you will have to use another `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

No the elif condition won't be checked.As soon as the if condition is evaluated as true the elif condition gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Python would only check the 'elif' or 'else' conditions only  if the 'if' condition returns false. If the first condition ('if' condition) returns true, it would ignore the other conditions.